# How to change a widget's language on Shuffle workspaces?

Tags: internationalization, widget, shuffle

I'm trying to test the i18n of my widget in Shuffle workspaces because is faster to test it here than on the Shuffle app but I don't know how to change the language of widgets in the workspace.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [line](https://github.com/nubank/shuffle/blob/master/src-fulcro/nubank/shuffle/common/i18n.cljs#L47) and change it to the language your prefer (`:es`, `:en`, `:pt`).

For example:

`([language] {::dictionary @dictionary ::language :es}))`

Shuffle workspace will automatically reload and show the widgets texts and values that you have internationalized in the language you chose.